# How to return an array of objects with a key of least value?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like below. How to return an array of objects containing the minimum value of bidAmount?

```
[
{userId:2,bidAmount:9200},
{userId:3,bidAmount:8500},
{userId:4,bidAmount:8100},
{userId:5,bidAmount:8100}
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
{userId:4,bidAmount:8100},
{userId:5,bidAmount:8100}
]
```

I tried Array.reduce to find minimum but it returns only one object

```
var min = result.reduce(function(res, obj) {
    return (obj.bidAmount < res.bidAmount) ? obj : res;
});
//Returns {userId: 4, bidAmount: 8100}
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce with an array as result set and check the `bidAmount`, if it is smaller or equal.

```js
const data = [{userId: 2, bidAmount: 9200}, {userId: 3, bidAmount: 8500}, {userId: 4, bidAmount: 8100}, {userId: 5, bidAmount: 8100}]
var minima = data.reduce((acc, el, index) => {
  if (!index || acc[0].bidAmount > el.bidAmount) return [el];
  if (acc[0].bidAmount === el.bidAmount) acc.push(el);
  return acc;
}, null);

console.log(minima);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get all the `bidAmounts` in an array. After that, get the indexes of the smallest `bidAmount` (and store them in `indexs`). Finally, just get and return the elements by the indexs.

```js
const data = [{userId:2,bidAmount:9200}, {userId:3,bidAmount:8500}, {userId:4,bidAmount:8100}, {userId:5,bidAmount:8100}];

var bidAmounts = data.map(el => el.bidAmount),
    minVal = Math.min(...bidAmounts),
    filteredData = data.filter(dataPoint => dataPoint.bidAmount == minVal);

console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: You could calculate `Math.min(...bidAmounts)` before hand instead of doing that in every loop.

Comment: I originally did that, but for some reason I removed it - I'm dumb . Thanks for catching it!

Comment: Is there a benefit to doing `bidAmounts.forEach( ... )` versus just filtering the data using minVal at this point do you think?

Comment: You cannot use `filter` and return indices. However, I was working on something very similar using `reduce`, and further lessened the code above using it (it was bothering me for a long time).

Comment: I was wondering if the indices were really necessary. Like maybe once you've got minVal, you could just do: `data.filter((item) => item.bidAmount === minVal)`.